# The [cent] tag needs to go

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm not fly like @WesleyDavid, so no fancy WoW references.

The [cent] tag looks like it's a typo and the only question under it got migrated to Unix & Linux already.

I'm thinking it needs to get whacked before it spreads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents: you're absolutely right!

Done!